# Build Python Applications

Tags: python, build

I have created  a python application and now want to build it.

I have read a bit about how to do it using `distutils` or `setuptools` or making wheels or eggs.  But most of them seem to be targeted at distribution of the package as a module which can be imported by other python applications(something like modules in python package index).

I have also read about `pyInstaller` but it seems out to spit out the binaries directly. 
When I started learning Java,  I learned rather very quickly how to build and deploy,  mostly as a Jar but it seems deployment for python isn't well documented.

Though I want to make a shell script which would build from the source files and make a binary,  I am also interested in learning other ways to deploy the application.

I want to make a shell script because it would help to distribute it for different Linux platforms.  Maybe could create a bat file after I find a solution for deploying in Linux

Answer (score 0):

I used  [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). After installing, you just have to make a simple setup.py.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'include_files':['icon.gif']} # include dependent files such as icon here

setup(
    name = "programname",
    version = "2.7",
    description = "---",
    executables = [Executable(script = "myfile.py", base="Win32GUI # specify the mainprogram *.py.
```

Then CD to this directory using CMD and execute:

```
python setup.py install
```

It will create a "build" folder containing the *.exe. Take care the cx_freeze installer installs to Python in the system path (in Windows at least).